# Binding library to Go and Lua with SWIG?

Tags: go, lua, swig

I've recently started a project using Go, and have pulled some libraries in. I'm using [wxGo](https://github.com/dontpanic92/wxGo) to bind wxWidgets to Go, and [GopherLua](https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua) to bind Lua to Go. This is all working well, and was pretty easy to set up. (Go is pretty cool like that.)

However, I've come to point where I'd like bind wxWidgets to Lua as well, but I'm new to SWIG, and I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is. I have some ideas involving generating the wxWidgets C++ wrapper library for Lua, then somehow loading that into Go, but I'm not that will even work.

How can I bind wxWidgets to both Go and Lua in my program?

Comment: Whilst that is technically possible it's probably quite a substantial undertaking to make it actually work. I suspect you'd be better off revisiting some design assumptions insteda.

Comment: My plan is to do most of the Core and UI work in Go, and use Lua to make the whole program more modifiable. I should be able to do without the wxWidgets Lua bindings, but it will make end user modifications more difficult. For now, I'm just moving on without the wxWidgets Lua bindings for the sake of the project, but if an easy solution comes up, I'd love to add them later.

Comment: I didn't say it's hard. It's easy enough, just a substantial amount of effort to actually do it, because for each and every type that matters in wxWidgets you'll have to write some combination of SWIG, Go, C++ and Lua to glue it across the boundary. .